# Is the sublocale determined by the double negation nucleus special among all the Boolean sublocales of a locale?

Tags: general-topology, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

In pointless topology, for any [locale](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locale) $A$ (a.k.a. complete Heyting algebra) its Heyting negation (a.k.a. pseudocompelement) $\neg : A \to A$ gives rise to a [nucleus](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nucleus) $\neg\neg: A \to A$.  As is also well known, the associated [sublocale](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sublocale) $A_{\neg\neg} = \{x \in A: \neg\neg x = x\}$ happens to be Boolean.

Is this sublocale the largest of all the Boolean sublocales of $A$?  If not, does $A_{\neg\neg}$ have a special property among its kind?

Here are related facts of which I am aware:

1. $A_{\neg\neg}$ is the *least* sublocale (that is, least of all, *possibly non-Boolean* sublocales) containing the zero of $A$.
2. The Boolean sublocales of $A$ are exactly the sublocales determined by nuclei of the form $((\cdot)\to a) \to a$ for $a \in A$. (Write $b(a)$ for such a sublocale.) For instance, $A_{\neg\neg} = b(0)$.
3. Nonetheless, it is not necessarily the case that $b(a) \subseteq b(0)$ for all $a \in A$.  This is essentially because $x \to a \equiv ((x \to a) \to 0) \to 0$ is not a law of Heyting algebras.

My references for those facts are *Stone Spaces* by Johnstone and *Frames and Locales* by Picado and Pultr.